# WiFi issue: /var/log/syslog and kern.log are too huge after I installed Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, 14.04, syslog

Freshly installed Ubuntu 14.04 last week and my WiFi was not working. I tried to get WiFi up in vain then I started using LAN as a workaround for my work.

And today I noticed syslog* was more than 50G and kern.log is 15G.  kern.log is full of:

```
kernel: [32263.171249] iwl3945 0000:10:00.0: Radio disabled by HW RF Kill switch
```

syslog is full of:

```
Apr 27 19:03:55 username NetworkManager[693]: dbus_g_proxy_cancel_call: assertion 'pending != NULL' failed
Apr 27 19:03:55 username NetworkManager[693]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: starting -> down
Apr 27 19:03:55 username NetworkManager[693]: <warn> Trying to remove a non-existant call id.
Apr 27 19:03:55 username wpa_supplicant[729]: Could not set interface wlan0 flags (UP): No such device
Apr 27 19:03:55 username wpa_supplicant[729]: nl80211: Could not set interface 'wlan0' UP
Apr 27 19:03:55 username wpa_supplicant[729]: Could not set interface wlan0 flags (UP): No such device
Apr 27 19:03:55 username wpa_supplicant[729]: WEXT: Could not set interface 'wlan0' UP
Apr 27 19:03:55 username wpa_supplicant[729]: wlan0: Failed to initialize driver interface
Apr 27 19:03:55 username NetworkManager[693]: <error> [1398621835.98218] [nm-supplicant-interface.c:997] interface_add_cb(): (wlan0): error adding interface: wpa_supplicant couldn't grab this interface.
```

I have disabled WiFi in system setting and logs have stopped.  How to deactivate/remove the problematic WiFi drivers?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your wireless card was disabled at your laptop's hardware switch.  There is often a function key that can re-enable the wireless card (Fn+F2 for me), or a physical switch somewhere on your device.

If you have switched out your wireless hardware since installing Ubuntu, it could also be a hardware address issue that can be resolved by modifying udev rules.  It sounds more like the hardware switch is turned off, though.